# How do I use a tigger event in MySQL to prevent a certain user from being deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am making a MySQL database to be used as part of my webgame app, in the database there is an admin user in that user table. As a sort of security protection, I need some way to use a trigger event to prevent Anyone from deleting that user on the rare chance that someone finds a way to run queries on my database.

Comment: If someone finds a way to run queries on your database, they likely already have more power than an "admin user"; what good would this protection do you? Still, it's a good question in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`signal`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html) syntax to raise an error in case a delete statement is issued for the admin user. Assuming you identify him by the condition `name='admin'`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER users_protect_admin_del_tr
BEFORE DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF old.name = 'admin' THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Admin deletion prevented';
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT:

As @Uueerdo commented, this trigger can easily be circumvented by updating the username and then deleting it (or just leaving it updated, which would probably break the system anyway). An additional trigger to prevent updating is required:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER users_protect_admin_update_tr
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF old.name = 'admin' THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Admin updating prevented';
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There should probably a similar update trigger to prevent the admin from being renamed too.

Comment: @Uueerdo good point! I've edited it into my answer.